# HTML / CSS. Floating(?) images / content to the left and right of more content

Tags: html, css, css-position, floating

this has been bothering me for a while now. My positioning with CSS/HTML is a little rusty and I'm having a lot of trouble floating an image to the left and the right of content, this is probably better explained by my codepen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYMyGr

Code:

```
.left-content {
float: left;
width: 60%
}
.right-content {
float: right;
width: 40%
}
.bracket-right {
float: right;
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
}
.bracket-left {
float: left;
position: absolute;
}

<div class="right-content">
<div class="bracket-left">
<img src="http://theconstant-gardener.com/wp-content/themes/constantgardener/assets/img/left-bracket.svg" />
</div>
<div class="content-testimonial">
  <p>Hello world, I am a testimonial hopefully wrapped in two brackets, one to the left; the other right. I enjoy being sandwiched in quite alot
</div>
<div class="bracket-right">
<img src="http://theconstant-gardener.com/wp-content/themes/constantgardener/assets/img/right-bracket.svg" />
</div>
</div>
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong and would like to learn from this, I tried searching around but couldn't find anything, I didn't really know what to search ^.^

Any help is massively appreciated. Thank you!

(Also, if anything I have done is bad practice let me know, I love to learn :) )

Comment: Which is the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to change:

`<img src="http://theconstant-gardener.com/wp-content/themes/constantgardener/assets/img/left-bracket.svg" />`
to `<img src="http://theconstant-gardener.com/wp-content/themes/constantgardener/assets/img/left-bracket.svg" align="left" />`

and `<img src="http://theconstant-gardener.com/wp-content/themes/constantgardener/assets/img/right-bracket.svg"/>` to `<img src="http://theconstant-gardener.com/wp-content/themes/constantgardener/assets/img/right-bracket.svg" align="right" />`

Adding the 'align' attribute to img tag makes it wrap around text. I guess you wanted a text wrapped between two images

Comment: As far as I know there is no `align` property.

Comment: I dont get what you just said. Did you try to do as I said? I EDITED in the ; symbols...incase you didnt add it.

Comment: I mean that Mozilla Developer Network has no reference of any `align` property; it is not supported neither by latest Firefox Nightly nor Chromium; and I can't find any W3C spec that defines it. But if it exists, I would love to see a reference.

Comment: Wait, I just found out what you needed. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Be aware that the `align` attribute was deprecated in [HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#adef-align-IMG) and is obsolete in [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#attr-img-align). You should use the `float` CSS property instead. And I am not the asker of the question :)

Comment: I didn't know about that, and I dont know any other solutions

Answer (score 0):

You have some error on your CSS and HTML coad 
1. CSS class `.left-content` and `.right-content` has no `;` in width. 
2. You must have to keep the `static` position of class `.bracket-right` and `.bracket-left`. 
3. You didnt set any CSS class for `content-testimonial;`.  
4. Set `float:left;` of class `.bracket-right`, `.bracket-left` and `.content-testimonial`. 
5. You didint close the tag `<p>` with `</p>`.

here is your aspected thing may be

```
<head>
<style>
.left-content {
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
}
.right-content {
    float: right;
    width: 40%;
}
.bracket-right {
    float: left;
}
.bracket-left {
    float: left;
}
.content-testimonial{
    float:left;
    text-align:justify;
    width:300px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="right-content">
  <div class="bracket-left"> <img src="http://theconstant-gardener.com/wp-content/themes/constantgardener/assets/img/left-bracket.svg" /> </div>
  <div class="content-testimonial">
    <p>Hello world, I am a testimonial hopefully wrapped in two brackets, one to the left; the other right. I enjoy being sandwiched in quite alot </p>
  </div>
  <div class="bracket-right"> <img src="http://theconstant-gardener.com/wp-content/themes/constantgardener/assets/img/right-bracket.svg" /> </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Just to let you know, my pen didn't save so I bodged the changes without checking them over just in case any body checked it, they were closed and everything was correct on the first take but I didnt save :(. Taking a look at your changes now :) Thanks for the reply